# Inserting multiple rows/records into another table from a filtered report

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vba

I'm having trouble inserting multiple rows/records into another table from a filtered report when the user clicks on CHECKOUT.

Image of report (as I have less than 10 rep): http://s12.postimg.org/otm0pl8cs/Untitled_1.jpg

```
'Inserts books in Order Details table
Dim strOrderDetailSQL As String
strOrderDetailSQL = "INSERT INTO Order_Details (OrderNo, ISBN, Quantity) VALUES ('5', ISBN_Cart, Quantity_Cart)"
DoCmd.RunSQL strOrderDetailSQL
```

Where order number 5 is just a test value. How can I have it insert all filtered records from a report?

As it currently stands, it only inserts the first record, but not both.

Comment: This query you have will only insert one record. If you want to do batch inserts, you will either have to loop through your report structure extracting the data items (orderno, isbn, qty) and insert each row at a time or you could do a batch insert.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, how would I go about doing a batch insert? Would an iteration be better? How do I get the iteration value (number of rows)?

I'm very new to SQL but I know a little Java which has helped me thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could help you

insert into tableA(column1,column2,...) values
select otherColumn1, otherColumn2,... where bla bla..

(I have used similar query in postgres)

Comment: The number of rows will also vary as the results are filtered, making the "insert into tableA(column1,column2,...)" approach not feasible. Is there a statement which determines the current number of rows? I could then perhaps use that for iteration? How would I modify my code to make it work as an iterator (im a noob with sql/vba)

Comment: you don't have to worry about the number of rows returned as they will always all be inserted.

What you need to make sure is equal is that number of columns in the select should be equal to the number of columns in the insert.

The DBMS will auto iterate through all the returned rows inserting each one of them. I have done this in Postgres but i know you can achieve it in MySQL as well.

Comment: I'll give that a go, thank you. :)

ps. Could you show me how I would rewrite my SQL code?

Comment: One of my columns will be a static integer, for example the order number 5 will be consistent for all entries. I think this may be why it wont work. :/

Comment: Here is a simple example you could experiment with; (I use Postgres 8.*)  
create table sample1(name character varying(255) , age int); 

create table sample2(otherName character varying(255));  

insert into sample2 values ('hosea');

insert into sample1 (name,age) select otherName,2 from sample2;

select name, age from sample1;

Comment: Hey ivanorone, thanks for your examples I managed to get it working :)